# Express JS REST API with MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, rest, express

I am doing an exercise with Express.js and MySQL. At the moment I have 4 files. The error is,

```
TypeError: areas.getAreas is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/--/--/--/src/routes/userRoutes.js:4:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/--/--/--/src/app.js:10:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
```

But I am sure I am declaring the variable and function so, I don't understand why is it happening.

I tried to get the value of the variable **areas** in the **userRoutes.js** file but console just show me an "{}". I also tried to change the sintaxis of the function of the **areas.js** file, writing it as function and not like an object.

The main file is, **app.js** and it contains:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan'); 
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = require('/--/--/--/db/connection.js');
const userRoutes = require('/--/--/--/routes/userRoutes.js');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 

connection(mysql);    
userRoutes(app);

app.listen(app.get('port'), ()=> {
    console.log('server on port 3000');
});
```

The next files are:

**connection.js**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function connection(mysql){
    mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'http://x.x.x.x',
        user: 'xxxxxxx',
        password: 'xxxxxxx',
        database: 'xxxxxxx'
    })
};
```

**areas.js**

```
'use strict';

let areasModel = {};
areasModel.getAreas = (callback) => {
    if(connection) {
        connection.query(
            "SELECT * FROM areas",
            (err, rows) => {
                if(err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                else {
                    callback(null, rows);
                }
            }
        );
    }
};

module.exports = areasModel;
```

**userRoutes.js**

```
'use strict';

const areas = require('../models/areas');

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
        areas.getAreas((err, data) => {
            res.json([]);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you try to `console.log(areas)` in `userRoutes.js`?

Comment: And I see usage of  `connection` variable in `areas.js` but seems like it was not declared.

Comment: Yeah..., I tried it, but the answer was "{}". I suppose when app charge, userRouters.js should charged and areas.js too. When invoked userRouters(app), it should can execute the content of areas.js too, no?

Answer (score 0):

try importing `connection.js` in `areas.js`,
maybe because never enter in that `if` statement, returns undefined